# Add gRPC servicers during runtime and provide interface to client

Tags: python, grpc

I am currently working on a project where I want to be able to add functionality to the gRPC server during runtime.

Once added, I want the client to be able to access the newly added functionality. I have two different ideas on how to approach this problem:

1. Transfer a generated gRPC file via another interface to the client and use it from there.
2. Using the Reflections Framework provided by Google ([Python gRPC Reflections](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/python/server_reflection.md)) to retrieve the available methods and interfaces.

Now I was wondering what the correct way to approach this problem is and am interested if there have already been solutions to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object that implements `grpc.GenericRpcHandler` interface, which contains a `service` method, can be registered on a gRPC server.  The service method then can resolve and return an arbitrary [`RpcMethodHandler`](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.RpcMethodHandler) based on the method name. You can customize that `service` method to dynamically return the appropriate handler at runtime.